# how can i write this query with laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have tables Users,departments,files and shareFiles. 
I want to write a query that when a user tries sending a file to another user, the share function should capture the title of the file and department of the user sending the file which would be saved in the shareFiles table.

- Users table: `id`, `department_id`
- Files table: `id`, `title`, `user_id`
- Department table: `id`, `name`
- ShareFiles table: `title`, `file`, `department_id`, `user_id`, `sender`, `to`

**Below is what i did in the share function**

```
public function shareFile(Request $request)
    {

        $userfile = new UserFile();
        $userfile->sender = \Auth::user()->username;
        $userfile->to = $request->user;
        $userfile->title = File::select('title')->where(['user_id' => \Auth::user()->id])
        ->orWhere('id','=','user_id')->get();

        $userfile->department = DB::table('departments')->select('departments.name')
        ->join('users','departments.id','=','users.department_id')
        ->where(['users.id' => \Auth::user()->id])
        ->get();

        $userfile->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $userfile->save();
        Session::flash('message','File successfully shared !!');
        return redirect('/hr/document');
    }
```

Comment: What is your exact question or problem?

Comment: eloquent `->get()` will return an array collection object, not a single value try to  select your value after, and if an user have more than one file, it will return all these files.

Comment: read what i wrote above the function guess i explained in details on there

Comment: @ekans can u please give me a sample query. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure of this syntax but something like this : `$file = File::select('title')->where(['user_id' => \Auth::user()->id])
        ->orWhere('id','=','user_id')->first();` (first() get only first result) then `$userfile->title = $file->title`should work

Comment: @ekans thanks it worked.... can you help with that of getting the department also thanks?

Comment: you just need to do the same thing : `$dept  = DB::table('departments')->select('departments.name')
        ->join('users','departments.id','=','users.department_id')
        ->where(['users.id' => \Auth::user()->id])
        ->first()` then `$userfile->department = $dept->name`

Comment: @ekans thanks.... but it is picking the wrong department of the user. can i always chat you up when i've issues in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
For title selection:

$file = File::select('title')->where(['user_id' => \Auth::user()->id]) ->orWhere('id','=','user_id')->first();

For Department:

$dept = DB::table('departments')->select('departments.name') ->join('users','departments.id','=','users.department_id') ->where(['users.id' => \Auth::user()->id]) ->first();
```

**Note:** You can also use value() and pluck() (in case if you need array of values) instead of select().